# How to import logo image in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add image before h1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyH0K.png)

```
import React from "react";


function Header(){
          
          return(     
                    <h1>Bikinin Kaos ID</h1>    
          );
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the image in the following manner

```
    import React from "react";
    import Image from '../img/logo-color.png'

function Header(){
          
          return(     
                   <img src={Image} alt='img' />
                    <h1>Bikinin Kaos ID</h1>    
          );
}

export default Header;
```

I have created a code sandbox demo You can check it here
[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-framework-4pbm2s?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, You need to import the logo from the location,

```
import logo from '../img/logo-color.png';
```

Then You need to use it like below,

```
<img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import avatar from "../../../assets/images/avatar.png";
```

and then,

```
<img src={avatar} alt="profile" />
```